# Aptly publish asking for password although --passphrase flag is set

Tags: apt, package-management, gpg, aptly

I unsuccessfully try publishing an APTLY snapshot (about 80GB) using

`aptly publish snapshot --batch=true --passphrase="SuperSecretPassWord" --distribution="mydistro" current-snapshot`

After about 15 minutes I'm always being asked for my key's passphrase.

Publishing another (much smaller, about 3GB) snapshot using the same command and key succeed without entering the passphrase:

`aptly publish snapshot --batch=true --passphrase="SuperSecretPassWord" --distribution="anotherdistro" another-snapshot`

Might this be because the first command just takes too long?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, Aptly 2 and GPG 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused by the passphrase cache entry expiring in gpg-agent. You could try setting `default-cache-ttl` and `max-cache-ttl` settings in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` to a number of seconds you find appropriate. Example below.

```
# set default cache time-to-live to 15 minutes
default-cache-ttl 900
# set max cache time-to-live to 1 hour
max-cache-ttl 3600
```

The `default-cache-ttl` is how long it saves the passphrase each time after you enter it. The `max-cache-ttl` is the longest it will be cached even if you keep entering it.

**Better solution**: use the [`internal`](https://www.aptly.info/doc/feature/pgp-providers/) PGP provider that does not have this problem.

Comment: I had to update the modifications in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90gpg-agent` and enable `gpg-agent` by `echo "use-agent" >>  ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`